# Unbinding certain links but not all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to unbind a link from all functions. When I do:

```
$('a').unbind();
```

It works perfectly. But obviously this is not what I want - I only want one specific link to not be manipulated by any functions. So I tried selecting the specific link:

```
$('.page1->index').unbind();
```

But this did not work, the function was still manipulating the link. I also tried

```
 $('a.page1->index').unbind();
```

But that did not work either. I feel like my second approach should work. Is there something I'm missing?

HTML:

```
<a id ="page1->index" href="#play1" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="fade" data-direction="reverse"></a>
```

Comment: Could you add the html to go with this? So we can see what your working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of your class is `page1->index`, then you need to escape '`>`' symbol, because it has a [special meaning](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) in `CSS` selectors:

```
$('.page1-\\>index').unbind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ID of the link. ID will be unique so you will get only one element in your jQuery selector

```
$('#yourLinkId').unbind();
```

Assuming your HTML is like this (with the ID)

```
<a href="somepage.aspx" id="yourLinkId">Wonderful Link</a>
<a href="somepage3.aspx" id="yourMagicLink">Magic Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclude all anchors that you don't need to manipulate by using a not selector or the not method.

For example

```
$('a').not('#DontUnbindThisAnchor').unbind()
```

The above code selects all anchors that don't have the id 'DontUnbindThisAnchor' and unbinds them